# Software to learn English words

Tags: windows, software-rec, dictionary

I am seeking software to expand my English vocabulary.
For example it can maybe let me add word - translation pairs and review them later.

I already have good electronic dictionary - Lingoes, but it doesn't have such function. So for now all my new English words (about 3000 of them) reside in the text file without translation :(

It should be preferably free. Duplicate word check or automatic review lessons would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [anki](http://ankisrs.net/), its a free (open source) flash card program. While not dedicated for translations/english studying its used to make flash card pairs (term+definition) that can then be printed or reviewed/tested on your PC.

Comment: I tried it out and it's pretty good. Not exactly what I wanted, but it proposes another way to do things: sometimes it's just easier to remember all those words than to manage gigantic list of them)

Comment: I take my comment back: multiple decks, card duplicates detection, review system, tagging - all this seem to be in place. The more I use it, more awesome it seems.